# xamarin android googlemap directions

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
requestApi = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?" + "mode=driving&" + "transit_routing_perference=less_driving&" + "origin=" + CurrentPostion.Latitude + "," + CurrentPostion.Longitude + "&" + "destination=" + Destionation + "&" + "key=AIzaSyCKxAGrqJaMBBXYMAI7gMvSJsjKrhA4_NQ ";
var address = "paris, france";
var requestUri = string.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?mode=driving&transit_routing_perference=less_driving&origin='"+CurrentPostion.Latitude+"','"+CurrentPostion.Longitude+"'&destination='"+Destionation+"'&key=AIzaSyCKxAGrqJaMBBXYMAI7gMvSJsjKrhA4_NQ", Uri.EscapeDataString(address));

HttpClient client;
client = new HttpClient();
client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
try
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync(requestApi);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Toast.MakeText(this, "result", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        JSONObject jSONObject = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray jSONArray = jSONObject.GetJSONArray("routes");
```

There is no jsonarry result what is wrong

Comment: does your result from the API call actually contain a routes array?

Comment: yes sir its contain it its return response

Comment: you might try a different json parser, like JSON.NET

Comment: Your question makes almost no sense can you explain what are you trying to do @HoKsh

Comment: problem solved thnx @Jason